# sending command to process using /proc

Tags: linux, command-line, process, echo

I have an application which runs as a process on a ubuntu server. This application has command line gui which allows me to type in a command, then press enter and the command runs. I am able to script the determination of the process id. I then script the following to send it a command:

```
# echo "command" > /proc/<PROCESSID>/fd/0
```

I have tried variations of

```
# echo "command" > /proc/<PROCESSID>/fd/0

# echo -e "command\r" > /proc/<PROCESSID>/fd/0

# echo -e "command\c" > /proc/<PROCESSID>/fd/0
# echo -e "\015" > /proc/<PROCESSID>/fd/0
```

I know the program is getting the command but does not execute it. I suspect this is because I am not physically pressing enter and possibly the command line is expecting this. Can someone advise me on how I am using this incorrectly or a better option?

Comment: 'Command line GUI'?  Or 'command line UI'?  If you are driving the process in the orthodox way, what do you type at the keyboard?  Or do you have to do something with the mouse, too?  How do you know that the process is getting the command?

Comment: Command line UI would i think best describe it, there is no mouse interaction. Typically I run the program via ssh and a text based command line appears. In this interface I can type in commands and they are executed. If I open a second separate ssh interface, I can type in echo "command" > /proc/<PROCESSID>/fd/0 after determining the process id and it appears in the original ssh interface but does not execute.

Comment: Related question: [Inject Keystroke to different process using Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11199135/929437)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that. /proc/fd/0 is (usually) not a pipe which you can write to and give the process input.

What you need to do, is invoke the process with its stdin coming from something that IS a pipe (or socket etc) so that you can write stuff into it.

A named pipe MAY work here (see mknod(1) or mkfifo(3) ).

Otherwise, you'll need a control program which sits in front of it and uses a pair of pipes to talk to it.

Comment: you were right, i was sending the text to the interface, not the program. I will need to do as you advised and create a program to act as a proper pipe. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the specifics, you probably need this: [expect](https://web.archive.org/web/20100604200647/http://www.nist.gov/mel/msid/expect.cfm)

Comment: I have read a bit on this, it seems this is the option to use if you are expecting a certain prompt to which you can programmatically respond. Would you still suggest this if there is no such prompt? I try to use as minimal and clean coding as possible but if using another library is the best answer, I will gratefully accept...

Comment: From your comment on the answer above, it seems like you are expecting some sort of prompt: "and a text based command line appears"